Where to Track the UTM Parameters Enabled in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?
Recently, we enabled the Web Analytics Connector in our lower environment. To verify whether the UTM parameters were working, we sent out a test email to our email IDs and checked the tracking details under Tracking → Sends → Test Send Emails.
However, upon clicking the specific email name that we intended to monitor, we couldn't find any data related to the UTM parameters configured in the WAC. Could you please guide me on where to check the tracking details for the UTM parameters of specific emails?

WAC simply adds query strings onto all links. You can leverage the _click dataview to verify these query strings were added.
There is no tracking/reporting of these query strings within Marketing Cloud
